# Is Ubuntu 16.04 on 2GB RAM practical?

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu

The neighbor's 2005 tech (desktop and laptop) both have 512MB with XP.  The plan is to replace XP with either lubuntu or Ubuntu (preferable).

lubuntu with 512M is tolerable on the desktop (Dell XPS400): not so with Ubuntu.   Before I buy any RAM (2GB Max) for either computer, I would like to know if I can expect users to have a responsive experience on Ubuntu with 2GB.  The latop is a EEE-PC 1000HE.

If you have experience running Ubuntu 16.04 on 2GB of RAM please state this in your response, hardware (SSD?), and comment if it is responsive.   If it is not, then I am inclined to just leave them with 512MB and install lubuntu.  Thank you

Update: Received temporary custody and here are the updated specs

- [Desktop Specs](http://www.cnet.com/products/dell-xps-400-pentium-d-820-2-8-ghz-1-gb-160-gb-lcd-19/specs/)   RAM:512MB
- [Notebook Specs](https://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks/Eee_PC_1000HE/)  RAM:2GB  Intel Atom N280 Atom @1.66Ghz

Comment: If the machines have 512MB RAM, I would assume they're quite old and would be more concerned with processor and graphics card to run Unity.  Can you post specs?

Comment: I tried Ubuntu 16.04 on a ThinkPad T60 with 3GB ram and it didn't do well. Responsiveness was slow and jumpy, and that's with a Core 2 Duo 2.16 GHz cpu. Lubuntu, Xubuntu, or Ubuntu Mate would be a better choice for the machine you mentioned.

Comment: I have 2GB RAM, quad-core Z3735, 1.33 GHz, 32GB SSD. I have used (64-bit) Ubuntu, Xubuntu & Ubuntu MATE, all run happily for me.

Comment: Have you considered puppy linux? Also, is this person used to Windows, otherwise suggesting Linux can lead to issues - In my personal experience. If he is willing to give it a try then that's cool.

Comment: User is willing to abandon XP in favor of Linux because another laptop with WIN7 is available.    Tasks include gmail, on-line banking , printing and watching movies.   No administration or adding new programs.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 32 bit version should work fine. There may be few glitches, but overall it will run good enough. Remember to keep a `swap` partition.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu with Unity is not the best option for a <2 GB of RAM computer. Try to install Lubuntu or Xubuntu, LXDE and XCFE are lighter than Unity DE.

<del>Add a swap partition, at least 1 GB.</del>

**EDIT**

Add a swap partition, at least 3 GB

Comment: 1 GB swap in this case might even not be enough.

Comment: Mmmm. Yeah, you're right.

Comment: There's no need to strikethrough text and mark an edit. You can just update the answer to read the way you want it to. :)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up installing all 3 (Ubuntu,lubuntu & xubuntu) the 2GB laptop.  Ubuntu was a little slow and the other two were snappy.  xubuntu seem to be just as snappy as lubuntu and its GUI is more similar to XP.

Comment: Give Ubuntu Mate a try, has most of Unity's functional features without load.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like since they are old, I would avoid Unity due to their processor. Lubuntu is still a great OS. I use it on my Pentium Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.5GHz and 4GB Ram.